# Stop multiple clicks vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vue.js application there items can be removed.

The div element looks like this:

```
 <div class="ride-delete" @click="delete">
      <p>Delete</p>
 </div>
```

This is the method that handles the `click`:

```
methods: {
    delete ()
    {
      swal({
        title: "Weet u het zeker?",
        text: "Het is niet mogelijk deze handeling te herstellen!",
        cancelButtonText: 'Stop',
        type: "error",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Ja, verwijder deze rit.",
        closeOnConfirm: false
      }, () => {
        RideService.destroy(this.ride)
          .then(() => {
            swal({
              title: "Rit succesvol verwijderd",
              type: "success",
              showCancelButton: false,
              timer: 2000,
              showConfirmButton: false
            });
            this.$router.go('/administratie/ritten');
          });
      });
    }
  }
```

So how can I make sure that if the user clicks 3 times fast after each other there will only be send one request. Right now there are send 3. So the button should be disabled if the user clicks once on it.

--EDIT--

```
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import RideService from '../../services/RideService';

export default {

  data () {
    return {
      ride: { user: {}, location: {}, type: {} },
      deleting: false
    }
  },

  route: {
  data ({ to }) {
      return RideService.show(this.$route.params.rideId)
        .then(function(data) 
        {
          this.ride = data.data.ride;
        }.bind(this));
    }
  }, 

  methods: {
    remove ()
    {
      if (!this.deleting) {
        this.deleting = true
        swal({
          title: "Weet u het zeker?",
          text: "Het is niet mogelijk deze handeling te herstellen!",
          cancelButtonText: 'Stop',
          type: "error",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
          confirmButtonText: "Ja, verwijder deze rit.",
          closeOnConfirm: false
        }, () => {
          RideService.destroy(this.ride)
            .then(() => {
              swal({
                title: "Rit succesvol verwijderd",
                type: "success",
                showCancelButton: false,
                timer: 2000,
                showConfirmButton: false
              });
              this.deleting = false
              this.$router.go('/administratie/ritten');
            });
        });

        this.deleting = false
      }  
    }
  }
}       
</script>
```

--EDIT 2--

```
<template>
  <div class="row center">
    <div class="panel ride">
      <div class="ride-title bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <strong class="ride-item-title-body">Rit van {{ ride.created_at }}</strong>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Naam</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.user.name }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Locatie van</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.from }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Locatie naar</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.from }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Beschrijving</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.description }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Kmz</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.kmz }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>kmp</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.kmp }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Uren</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.hour }} uur</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Google maps</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.maps }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Datum</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.created_at }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Tijd</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.time }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Factureerbare tijd</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.billabletime }} uur</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Type</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.type.name }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item">
        <div class="ride-edit">
          <p>Edit</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-delete" @click="remove">
          <p>Delete</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>            
</template>

<script>

import swal from 'sweetalert';
import RideService from '../../services/RideService';

export default {

  data () {
    return {
      ride: { user: {}, location: {}, type: {} },
      processing: false
    }
  },

  route: {
  data ({ to }) {
      return RideService.show(this.$route.params.rideId)
        .then(function(data) 
        {
          this.ride = data.data.ride;
        }.bind(this));
    }
  }, 

  methods: {
    remove ()
    {
       if (this.processing === true) {
        return;
      } 
        this.processing = true
        swal({
          title: "Weet u het zeker?",
          text: "Het is niet mogelijk deze handeling te herstellen!",
          cancelButtonText: 'Stop',
          type: "error",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
          confirmButtonText: "Ja, verwijder deze rit.",
          closeOnConfirm: false
        }, () => {
          RideService.destroy(this.ride)
            .then(() => {
              swal({
                title: "Rit succesvol verwijderd",
                type: "success",
                showCancelButton: false,
                timer: 2000,
                showConfirmButton: false
              });
              this.processing = false
              this.$router.go('/administratie/ritten');
            });
        });

        this.processing = false
    }
  }
}       
</script>
```

Comment: I'd suggest storing the state of the async request in a data property (e.g. `processing: false` and when the user clicks on the element, set it to `true`), and then within the `delete()` method check the state to continue or stop the code. Finally, reset the state in success/failure handlers.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Just posted an example :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'd suggest storing the state of the async request in a data property (e.g. processing: false and when the user clicks on the element, set it to true), and then within the delete() method check the state to continue or stop the code. Finally, reset the state in success/failure handlers.

For instance:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    processing: false
  },
  
  methods: {
    delete(el) {
      // terminate the function
      // if an async request is processing
      if (this.processing === true) {
        return;
      } 
      
      // set the async state
      this.processing = true;
      
      var paragraphs = Array.from(this.$el.querySelectorAll('p'));
      
      // simulating the async request
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (paragraphs.length) {
          paragraphs.shift().remove();
        }
        
        // on success or failure
        // reset the state
        this.processing = false;
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Processing: {{ processing }} <br>
  <button @click.prevent="delete()">
    Click here to delete a paragraph 
  </button>

  <p v-for="1 in 3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis officia adipisci, omnis cum odit modi perspiciatis aliquam voluptatum consectetur. Recusandae nobis quam quisquam magnam blanditiis et quos beatae quasi quia!
  </p>
```

Comment: Awesome solution. But for some reason processing does not change in my vue.js application. I've recorded the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByeuR1N3nhXId1o3X1JPNUZIaWs/view  in edit 2 above I've put my current code with your idea. What could be wrong here? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Jamie It seems the `processing` is being reassigned too early--outside the promise success/failure handlers. Notice the `this.processing = false` which is outside the `.then()`. Try removing that line and placing it within an error handler inside either the `.then()` or a `.catch()` method.

Comment: You are the best. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 24):

Since Vue 2.1.4, there's a really simple solution to this:

Change:

```
<div class="ride-delete" @click="delete">
   <p>Delete</p>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="ride-delete" @click.once="delete">
   <p>Delete</p>
</div>
```

`@click.once` only runs the target method one time.

In my case, it solved a problem with login, where multiple clicks would append path chunks to the URL, like this: `localhost:8000/admin/oms/admin/oms/admin/oms`.

Here the description in the official Vue documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: The .once directive should only be used if the button on that rendered page will only be used literally once, otherwise the accepted answer's logic is what you want.

Comment: I love vuejs! hahaha...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Using `@click.once` is bad in most cases, because form validation should be called, and resubmit form is needed.
In this situation, using a flag `loading` or `processing` is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="ride-delete" v-show="!deleting" @click="delete">
    <p>Delete</p>
</div>
```

---

```
methods: {
  delete ()
  {
    if (!this.deleting) {
      this.deleting = true

      swal({
        title: "Weet u het zeker?",
        text: "Het is niet mogelijk deze handeling te herstellen!",
        cancelButtonText: 'Stop',
        type: "error",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Ja, verwijder deze rit.",
        closeOnConfirm: false
      }, () => {
        RideService.destroy(this.ride)
          .then(() => {
            swal({
              title: "Rit succesvol verwijderd",
              type: "success",
              showCancelButton: false,
              timer: 2000,
              showConfirmButton: false
            });
            this.deleting = false;
            this.$router.go('/administratie/ritten');
          });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But for some reason this.deleting does not change to true after the if statement! What could be wrong. I'm looking for more then 1 hour now but cannot solve the problem! Please see my code in the edit section above. Would really appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

You better use `@click.once` modifier provided by vue 2.1.4+ itself.

Answer (score 0):

**simple way** (vue directive)

```
<button v-click="ajaxPromiseFn">simple way prevent multiple clicks</button>

// npm install vue-stop-multiple-click
const stopMultipleClick = require('vue-stop-multiple-click')
Vue.directive('click', stopMultipleClick)
```

[online demo](https://en777.github.io/vue-stop-multiple-click/example.html)

[github](https://github.com/En777/vue-stop-multiple-click)

[npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-stop-multiple-click)

Answer (score -9):

Try this

```
<div class="ride-delete" v-on:click="delete()">
    <p>Delete</p>
</div>
```